# Getting the instance of the canvas d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to d3js and am trying to save an instance of the d3js canvas object. After it is saved, I would like to get the elements of the saved d3js canvas.

**EDITED QUESTION:**
Essentially what I would like to do is access the elements that are drawn inside the d3.json function, after they are drawn.

Below is my code html and javascript:

```
HTML Before d3.json load:
<div id="model_container" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 20%">

HTML After d3.json load:
<div id="model_container" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 20%">
.
.
.
.
 <g id='reactions'>
     <g id='r0' class='reaction'>
       <g class='reaction-label-group' transform='translate(360,500)'>
         <text class='reaction-label label'>HELLO</text>
       <g id='r1' class='reaction'>
         <g class='reaction-label-group' transform='translate(365,500)'>
           <text class='reaction-label label'>HELLO2</text>
</div>

JavaScript:
var canvasMap = d3.json(document.getElementById("model").value, function(error, data) {
     if (error) console.warn(error);
     var options = {menu: 'all', canvas_size_and_loc: { x: '200', y: '200', width: '5000', height: '5000' }};
     var b = escher.Builder(null, data, null, d3.select('#model_container'), options);
     b.map.new_reaction_from_scratch('GAPD',{ x: 350, y: 315 }, 90);
     b.map.new_reaction_from_scratch('PGK',{ x: 950, y: 315 }, 90);
     b.map.select_all();
   });

   canvasMap.selectAll(".reaction-label-group").each(function (d) { console.log(d) });
```

Comment: D3 doesn't use <canvas>...

Comment: Apologies for my terminology, again I am new d3js. By canvas I meant drawing area. But essentially what I would like to do is access the elements that are drawn inside the d3.json function, after they are drawn. I will edit my original question.

Comment: I'd recommend you use the d3 way of drawing using selections/enter functions.  That way the drawn elements will be accessible as selections and used or updated or removed later.

Comment: @dandavis you can create a `<canvas>` with D3: D3 is render agnostic, meaning that it can create SVG, canvas, HTML etc... Where did you get this information?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: from experience; all i've ever seen is svg stuff, but you're probably right it's _possible_.

Comment: @dandavis It's not only possible: a lot of the examples in the API are with canvas. Here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/ad70335eeef6d167bc36fd3c04378048 And here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/31ce330646fa8bcb7289ff3b97aab3f5 Or here: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3783604 The examples abound. Actually, when the new API was released last year, most of the examples were with canvas, very few of them with SVG.

Answer (score 1):

First, var canvasMap = d3.json() won't return anything of what you are looking for, it:

> Returns a new request to get the JSON file at the specified url with
>   the default mime type application/json ([API docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#json))

Secondly, and what I think is the core of your question:

> Essentially what I would like to do is access the elements that are
>   drawn inside the d3.json function, after they are drawn.

If you are drawing elements with d3.json like so (or any other way):

```
d3.json("file.json", function(error, data) {
    // add elements based on json data:
    var select = svg.selectAll("path")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .....  // and so on
})
```

Then you won't be able to select those elements with this code:

```
var selection;
d3.json("file.json", function(error, data) {
    // add elements based on json data:
    selection = svg.selectAll("path")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      ..... 
})
selection.attr("fill","steelblue")
```

Why? Because d3.json is asynchronous - the code does not execute in the order it is written. The callback function in  d3.json, the code between `d3.json("file",function(error,data) {` and `})` is executed only after the json file is loaded. While that file loads, the code outside the callback continues to execute. My line `selection.attr("fill","steelblue")` won't do anything because selection doesn't hold anything yet - the json is still loading.

If you want to select things that are added in the callback, place that code in the callback itself:

```
var selection;
d3.json("file.json", function(error, data) {
    // add elements based on json data:
    selection = svg.selectAll("path")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      ..... 

     selection.attr("fill","steelblue")
})
```

It'll execute after the file is loaded and after the elements are appended.

Comment: I really appreciate your concise explanation. Thank you for that. I implemented your suggestion but I have one more question. When I try to extract the "HELLO" or "HELLO2" from `<text class='reaction-label label'>HELLO</text>`, I get a svg object. Here is the code I used for the extraction `d3.selectAll(".reaction-label-group").each(function (d) { reactionsVar.push(d.path); });` and here is the console log: `[Array(2)]
0
:
(2) [g, g, parentNode: html]`

Comment: If you want to access the text you could use: `textSelection.text()`. If you have a selection of many texts then .each(function(d) { `d3.select(this).text()` should work. However, it is difficult to answer questions in comments, if you have a new question you should post a new question: you will get a bigger audience and potentially better answers, and there is more room to show what you are trying to do and more room to answer.

Comment: Thanks again. I will post it as a separate question.